# How to handle errors for Not found key in Rust

Tags: rust, error-handling

I'm trying to capture errors on Rust, but I don't want the program to exit if I found it. I'm very new to Rust. Basically, I want to find a key from the Windows registry and if it doesn't exist, then create it.

Im using a crate called `winreg` for that.

This would be a section of my program:

```
fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    ...
    ...
    ...

    key.set_value("TestSZ", &"written by Rust")?;

    // here I'm getting a value that exists
    let sz_val: String = key.get_value("TestSZ")?;
    
    // but this key doesn't exist
    let other: String = key.get_value("NOT_EXISTING_KEY")?;

    println!("TestSZ = {}", sz_val);
    println!("TestSZ = {}", other);

    Ok(())
}
```

If I compile that I receive this in the console:

```
And now lets write something...
An existing key has been opened
TestSZ = written by Rust
Error: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "Couldn't find the pecified file." }
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\playground.exe` (exit code: 1)
```

In a pseudocode way, I would like something like:

```
if other == null {
println!("Nothing found!");
create_key();
}
```

If I analize `get_value` it looks like this:

`pub fn get_value<T: FromRegValue, N: AsRef<OsStr>>(&self, name: N) -> io::Result<T>`

I don't know what that means. I've been reading about errors and everything I do fails.

If I do `let other: String = key.get_value("NOT_EXISTING_KEY").expect("Failed to read product name");` then the program exits, showing the error.

But I don't want the program to fail, I want to capture the error and do a different flow if I don't find the key (for example, create it).

Does anyone know how can I deal with this?

Comment: The [error-handling chapter of the official book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html) explains `Result` in some detail, so you might want to read through that if the tutorials you've already found were lacking.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I was asking more about how to capture the error without crashing the program. I'm very new to Rust. 2 weeks only :(

Comment: Sure, and the book explains that as well. I hope my comment didn't come across as criticism because I didn't mean it that way, just as a suggestion to save you some time. Enjoy Rust, and happy hacking!

Comment: Oh, no no . Don't worry. I know. In fact, thanks a lot for the comment and the suggestion. That book is a great resource, I agree with you

Answer (score 1):

In Rust, a function that can fail usually returns a `Result<OkType, ErrorType>` data type. This type is a structured enum, which means, that it can tell you not only if error has occured, but also what kind of error, so you could act accordingly.

You can process enums with `match` statements. Or alternatively, `Result` type has shortcuts like `Result::unwrap` or `Result::expect` that basically say: "If there is an error, just tell me what kind and crash the program."

I'm not very familiar with Windows Registry, so I'm not sure how bulletproof the following code snippet is, but it should give you an idea on how you can process errors with a `match` statement.

```rust
fn main() {
  // ...

  let anykey_value = match key.get_value("AnyKey") {
    // If the key is present, initialize `anykey_value` variable
    // with the returned value
    Ok(value) => value,
    // If the key is not found, do the following steps:
    Err(error) => {
      println!("Nothing found!");
      // Try to set an empty string as the value for "AnyKey".
      // If fails: panic with the following message.
      key.set_value("AnyKey", &"").expect("Failed to create key \"AnyKey\"");
      // Initialize `anykey_value` variable with an empty string.
      ""
    }
  }
  
  // Will print the value stored in "AnyKey"
  // or an empty string, if the key was just created.
  println!("AnyKey = {}", anykey_value);
  
  // ...
}
```

Also you can checkout [Error handling chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-00-error-handling.html) from The Rust Programming Language book. It might be helpful.

Comment: Note that [`create_subkey`](https://docs.rs/winreg/0.9.0/winreg/struct.RegKey.html#method.create_subkey) "*will just open key if it already exists*", and on success it "*returns a tuple with the created subkey and its disposition, which can be `REG_CREATED_NEW_KEY` or `REG_OPENED_EXISTING_KEY`*".  However, I think in this case OP wants to set some (unspecified) *value* for the given name, not create a key?  That is, using [`set_value`](https://docs.rs/winreg/0.9.0/winreg/struct.RegKey.html#method.set_value) instead.

Comment: Yes. The subkey exists in this case. With the solution above it gives me an error in `get_value`: 
```
the trait `FromRegValue` is not implemented for `&str`
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it this way:

```
match key.get_value("NOT_EXISTING_KEY") {
        Ok(value) => {
            println!("found: {}", value);
            value
        },
        Err(err) => {
            println!("not found: {}", err);
            String::from("")},
    };
```

It was expecting a `String`

Comment: …but this doesn’t set the value in the registry, though that would be a simple modification.